# Accessing external user details for a Microsoft Teams meeting

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We tried Powershell and Graph API to collect some level of detail about users that are not part of our tenant ID. We can see the kind of information on Microsoft Teams Admin Portal but the same information is not available via any of APIs.

Did anyone have any luck with this?

Comment: Can you show us specifically what information you're trying to retrieve? What methods were you using with PowerShell/Graph? Was any code partially successful? If you do have code that was close, please show us what you have/where you're stuck.

Comment: Hi @Palezvar, Do you want to get details for guest user's in your tenant ? You can refer below graph API to get user details based on user email or object id https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Here is my process to test this 1) I used CQDPowerShell 2.0.0 to locate a sample conference call with one user from my tenant ID. The organizer and the other guests are not part of my tenant ID. 2) I take the conference ID and use Graph API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/[call_id]) to collect the call details. 3) The only participant I can clearly see is the attendant that belongs to my tenant ID, The rest shows as external in display name. I can see the id and tenant id in the return for these external users. Can I see email and name for these external users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We contacted Microsoft and they told us that what we are experiencing is as per design. We cannot see user details of conference attendants that are not part of our managed environment when we pull the Teams call details via API.